# IIS: Remove http and force https

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have a simple website and I would like to eliminate the www and force it to be https.

I managed to get 3 of the possible combinations working but am stuck on the last one.

- http://website.tld  ->  https://website.tld  (OK)
- https://website.tld  ->  https://website.tld  (OK)
- http://www.website.tld  ->  https://website.tld  (OK)
- **https://www.website.tld  ->  https://website.tld  (KO)**

---

I am using URL rewrite with code borrowed from other questions asked here.  I have the following 2 rules enabled:

```
    <rule name="Remove www" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I have the following URL redirects:

- www.website.tld → https://website.tld
- (*) → https://website.tld

Any idea how I can cover this condition?

Thanks

Comment: According to your url rewrite rules, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. [Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZPfR.png). I suggest you could try to use fail request tracing to troubleshoot what has happened. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the order of the rules? Sometimes that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input.

This is how I solved my problem.

```
<rule name="Remove www" enabled="true">
  <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I added the *stopProcessing* tag **only** to the second rule.

I modified my DNS record leaving only the following rule:

```
CNAME Record    www     website.tld.
```

In IIS I added (reinstated) the bindings for both the domain with and without **www**.

My reasoning as to why this worked is the followed are

- The website can handle both www.website.tld and website.tld.
- The URL Rewrite rules will handle the redirection.

A call to the site may both a removal of the www as well as the move to https.  Allowing a rewrite rule to do both (disabling *stopProcessing*) allows this to happen.